# Element is not clickable at point (x,y)

Tags: java, selenium

I have the following exception:

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Element is not clickable at
>   point (1057.38330078125, 673.13330078125). Other element would receive
>   the click:
>
> button id="ID4b6a687af6934e35b6f355f6305dc481"
>   data-layout="hbox" class="hux-ui-button" type="button"
>   role="button">

[image]

As you can see, I try to click on the Button "Speichern". But strangely the error says he can´t click on the position but the other element IS the Button I want to click on.

Do you know why and how I can work around this?

xpath = `//span[text()='Speichern'`

FF  = 43.0

Selenium = 2.49.

Comment: Do you get a single element by executing `$x("//span[text()='Speichern']")` in the console? Do you have a fixed banned/menu in the page?

Comment: Thats the result: Array [ <span.hux-ui-button-text.hux-ui-text> ] . The bar with those three buttons is relative.

Comment: do you have a fixed banner like twitter https://twitter.com/search?q=twitter ? Try to take a screenshot with Chrome when the exception occurs to see what is hiding your button.

Comment: Those buttons look disabled in your screenshot.  Are they?  Perhaps that's the problem.

Comment: No the buttons are not disabled - I can click on them after the scripted ended and the expected action happens. While the test I see that the button is kinda selected (color changed like i hover over it) but its not clicked.

Comment: If you mean that the bar is fix in the browser windows your right. While i scroll the bar doesnt move.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you told the driver to click on the span, not the button.  Try modifying your xpath to point to the button.  I THINK this would work:

```
//span[text()='Speichern']/..
```

It does assume that there is only the one element with that text, and looks for the parent, which is your button.

Comment: This is the only element with this name. I also tested it with the xPath to to Button and to the span - same result. I also implemented a wait but it doesn´t change the outcome :(

Answer (score 0):

Exception clearly states you are going to `click` on `span` while `button` element would receive the click, So you need to click on `button` instead of `span` as below :-

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button.hux-ui-button")).click();
```

or

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//span[text()='Speichern']/parent::button")).click();
```

**Edited** :- If still you are facing same issue try using `JavascriptExecutor` to perform click as below :-

```
WebElement el = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//span[text()='Speichern']/parent::button"));
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click()", el);
```

Comment: @KevinJanke Ok if you are still facing same issue try using `JavascriptExecutor` to perform click, see edited answer..:)

Comment: Ah did a mistake - with the JavascriptExecutor i get a different error: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.selenium.framework.base.Driver cannot be cast to org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor. I had to change a the code a bit because the Driver is a singelton in my framework.

Answer (score 0):

Sooo ... I just asked one Pro-Programmer ;).

I had to updated my singelton with this:

```
public static Optional<JavascriptExecutor> getExecutor() {
WebDriver checkdriver = Driver.getWebInstance();

final JavascriptExecutor executor;

if (checkdriver instanceof JavascriptExecutor ){

    executor = (JavascriptExecutor)checkdriver;

}
else
{
    executor = null;
}
return Optional.ofNullable(executor);
}
```

and added this in the actual page object:

```
WebElement el = Driver.getInstance().findElement(By.xpath(".//span[text()='Speichern']/parent::button"));

Driver.getExecutor().ifPresent( (executor) -> executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", el) );
```

now it works. Thx :)